# Use google pubsub with actionscript/air client

Tags: google-app-engine, flash, actionscript, air, google-cloud-pubsub

I have to implement google pubsub service in flash air client, in order to receive push messages from google app engine. After a lot of google seach, I did not found any example or discussion about this. 
Does anyone has already done this? 
If not, I will publish my solution, ... 
Thanks for your help!